# Can these scrapers be used to remove paint from millwork?

Tags: paint, removal

I was looking for some feedback on [Allway](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQMZ9C) and [Bahco](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000288LOW) contour scrapers I came across on Amazon.  I have some original millwork (100 yrs +) that I will first apply `Peel Away 1` to it and then use one of these scrapers to clean out grooves etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used similar scrapers with good results.For really fine details you might also get a dental type pick. Care must be taken with soft woods as you can scrape away some of the contours. The mutiple heads may make it easier to follow peaks and valleys.